# How to get all nested child's data in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database structure below. How do I get the value of `room_name_public`? I want to retrieve all those values and show it in a list view. Here, `55aqdTkLPrMwB6H0KX4Z0RUe6s52` is a Firebase userID and `-KcqR5Db5BidD0XpQ1z1` is created by the `push()` function.

[image]

Comment: Do you want them "per user"? That is, you want to show all the values with key "room_name_pucblic" for a given user, right?

Comment: Ok so you want all the child nodes of "public_rooms" node, right?

Comment: yes all the nodes of "public_rooms"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, you can try in this way.

Create a plain object, like this:

```
public class Room {
    String room_name_pucblic;

    public Room() {

    }

    public Room(String room_name_pucblic) {
        this.room_name_pucblic = room_name_pucblic;
    }

    public String getRoom_name_pucblic() {
        return room_name_pucblic;
    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("room_name_pucblic", room_name_pucblic);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Next, in your activity or fragment, declare and define the listener:

```
ValueEventListener roomsValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for ( DataSnapshot userDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {
            if (userDataSnapshot != null) {
                for ( DataSnapshot roomDataSnapshot : userDataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {
                    Room room = roomDataSnapshot.getValue(Room.class);

                    yourList.add(room.getRoom_name_pucblic());
                    yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

mFirebaseDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(roomsValueEventListener);
```

I suppose that `mFirebaseDatabaseReference` is the firebase reference of your `public_rooms` node. `yourList` is an ArrayList of strings, connected to your adapter for the list view.

Hope this helps

**Update**

If you want to fetch user's rooms, knowing an userId, you have to edit the previous approach in this way:

```
ValueEventListener roomsValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for ( DataSnapshot roomDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ) {
            Room room = roomDataSnapshot.getValue(Room.class);

            yourList.add(room.getRoom_name_pucblic());
            yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});


mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(roomsValueEventListener);
```

Comment: and what if I want to fetch rooms according to users (55aqdTkLPrMwB6H0KX4Z0RUe6s52) userID?

Comment: the update dint work, my database reference is somewhat like this, String userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID);

Comment: In this case, change last line of my update in this way: `mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(roomsValueEventListener);`

Comment: dont we have to reference our parent node, that is "public_rooms"?

Comment: If you reference the parent node, you have to add the `.child(userId)` to the DatabaseReference you are making..in order to "point" to the correct node you are expecting

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394), I got this error

Comment: I updated the last lines..It seems that you are passing null value..be sure that `mFirebaseDatabaseReference` in my last two lines is exaclty pointing to the node `public_rooms`